# Kotlin refer global variable from function

Tags: kotlin

Here is my code

```
var offset=0 //Global offset
fun foo(){
    bar(offset)
}

fun bar(offset:Int){//Function argument offset
    .......
    .......
    .......
    if(baz()){
        .......
        .......
        offset+=10 // I want to update the global offset, but function argument offset is reffered here
        bar(offset)
    }
}

fun baz():Boolean{
    .......
    .......
}
```

How can I refer to the global variable "offset" within the function bar(offset:Int)?
Is it not possible in Kotlin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In kotlin the function parameters are immutable (is val, not var!), so, you can't update offset argument inside bar function.

Finally, If you put these codes inside a class, then you can access global variables in a class with same name of your function parameter by 'this' keyword, like this:

```
class myClass{
    var offset=0 //Global offset
    fun foo(){
        bar(offset)
    }

    fun bar(offset:Int){//Function argument offset
        .......
        if(baz()){
            .......
            this.offset+=10 // I want to update the global offset, but function argument offset is reffered here
            .......
        }
    }

    fun baz():Boolean{
        .......
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can refer to the file level variable by prefixing it with the package name in this case:

```
package x

var offset = 0 // Global offset

fun bar(offset: Int) { // Function argument offset
    x.offset += 10 // Global offset
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    bar(5)
    println(offset) // Global offset
}
```